# The client and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a common algorithm Azure Storage

Tags: asp.net, .net, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

For the past month I've been running a web app in azure using ASP.NET MVC (.NET 4.6).

It's all been working fine until now however all the sudden I see the following exception being thrown constantly:

> Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException: The underlying
>   connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive. --->
>   System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An
>   unexpected error occurred on a receive. --->
>   System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The client and server cannot
>   communicate, because they do not possess a common algorithm    at
>   System.Net.SSPIWrapper.AcquireCredentialsHandle(SSPIInterface
>   SecModule, String package, CredentialUse intent, SecureCredential scc)
>   at
>   System.Net.Security.SecureChannel.AcquireCredentialsHandle(CredentialUse
>   credUsage, SecureCredential& secureCredential)    at
>   System.Net.Security.SecureChannel.AcquireClientCredentials(Byte[]&
>   thumbPrint)    at
>   System.Net.Security.SecureChannel.GenerateToken(Byte[] input, Int32
>   offset, Int32 count, Byte[]& output)    at
>   System.Net.Security.SecureChannel.NextMessage(Byte[] incoming, Int32
>   offset, Int32 count)    at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32
>   count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)    at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst,
>   Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)    at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult
>   lazyResult)    at
>   System.Net.TlsStream.CallProcessAuthentication(Object state)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)    at
>   System.Net.TlsStream.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult result)
>   at System.Net.TlsStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
>   at System.Net.PooledStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32
>   size)    at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeaders(Boolean async)
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()    at
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.ExecuteSync[T](RESTCommand`1
>   cmd, IRetryPolicy policy, OperationContext operationContext) in
>   c:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Core\Executor\Executor.cs:line
>   695    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.ExecuteSync[T](RESTCommand`1
>   cmd, IRetryPolicy policy, OperationContext operationContext) in
>   c:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Core\Executor\Executor.cs:line
>   604    at
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlobContainer.Exists(Boolean
>   primaryOnly, BlobRequestOptions requestOptions, OperationContext
>   operationContext) in c:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Blob\CloudBlobContainer.cs:line
>   1406    at BoligsideUtility.ImageService.GetBlockBlob(String
>   containerName, String blobName) in
>   C:\Users\NM\Dropbox\Projects\Boligside\BoligsideUtility\ImageService.cs:line
>   59    at BoligsideUtility.ImageService.GetImageUrl(ResImage img) in
>   C:\Users\NM\Dropbox\Projects\Boligside\BoligsideUtility\ImageService.cs:line
>   71    at Boligside.ViewModels.ResImageVm..ctor(ResImage image) in
>   C:\Users\NM\Dropbox\Projects\Boligside\Boligside\ViewModels\ImageViewModels.cs:line
>   22    at Boligside.ViewModels.ReviewVm..ctor(Review r) in
>   C:\Users\NM\Dropbox\Projects\Boligside\Boligside\ViewModels\ReviewVms.cs:line
>   74    at Boligside.ViewModels.HomeVm.<>c.<.ctor>b__21_2(Review x) in
>   C:\Users\NM\Dropbox\Projects\Boligside\Boligside\ViewModels\HomeViewModel.cs:line
>   35    at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectListIterator`2.MoveNext()
>
>   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
>
>   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)    at
>   Boligside.ViewModels.HomeVm..ctor(RealestateSiteDbContext context) in
>   C:\Users\NM\Dropbox\Projects\Boligside\Boligside\ViewModels\HomeViewModel.cs:line
>   35    at Boligside.Controllers.HomeController.Index() in
>   C:\Users\NM\Dropbox\Projects\Boligside\Boligside\Controllers\HomeController.cs:line
>   129    at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase
>   controller, Object[] parameters)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2
>   parameters)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.b__39(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.b__3d()
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.b__3f()
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass33.b__32(IAsyncResult asyncResult)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.<>c__DisplayClass2b.b__1c()
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.b__1e(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)

The line where the exception happens is this one:

```
CloudBlobContainer container = BlobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);
```

In this line I essentially call the azure blob API to get the container reference of the corresponding container name.

The strange thing is; I published my project again and the error disappeared.

However, the next day (today) the error reappeared.

Comment: did you use retry logic in the method that calls blob storage?

Comment: @Aravind I didn't. But the thing is, when the error happened it happened to me every time I refreshed as well. So even if I retried 5 times I don't think it would have mattered.

Comment: Is it possible that you're using an old version of SSL/TLS?  For example, have you set      ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;     in your codebase, or are forcing the host to use SSL?  The error indicates that your client and the Azure Storage Service don't share an SSL/TLS protocol